# Nativescript Angular SegmentedBar item dynamic title

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'd like to build a SegmentedBar with a dynamic title, for example: "Notes (5)" where 5 is the number of notes showed in these segment.

My problem is I'm not able to access segment title in code.
I'm generating all titles something like this:

```
this.pageItems = [];
let segmentedBarItem = <SegmentedBarItem>new SegmentedBarItem();
segmentedBarItem.title = 'Notes (' + order.notes.length + ')';
```

How can update segmentedbar item title when notes.length changes?

If I create again all segmentedBarItems the segment position changes to first segment, and I don't want to change position, only update the title of a segment.

Regards
Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO not create new segmented bar item but get the reference to the already created ones and change their title. Playground app demonstrating the above with TypeScript [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=BeQT5u).

Using Observable view model to create the bar items and the bound `notes`

***home-view-model.ts***

```
import { SegmentedBar, SegmentedBarItem } from "ui/segmented-bar";
import { Observable } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';

export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {
    private getSegmentedBarItems = () => {
        let segmentedBarItem1 = new SegmentedBarItem();
        segmentedBarItem1.title = "Notes (0)";
        let segmentedBarItem2 = new SegmentedBarItem();
        segmentedBarItem2.title = "Notes (0)";
        return [segmentedBarItem1, segmentedBarItem2];
    }

    segmentedBarItems: Array<SegmentedBarItem> = this.getSegmentedBarItems();
    selectedBarIndex: number;
    firstCounter: number;
    secondCounter: number;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.selectedBarIndex = 0;

        this.firstCounter = 0;
        this.secondCounter = 0;
    }

    changeBarTitleOne() { 
        let segBarItemOne = this.segmentedBarItems[0];
        segBarItemOne.title = 'Notes (' + (++this.firstCounter) + ')';
    }

    changeBarTitleTwo() {
        let segBarItemOne = this.segmentedBarItems[1];
        segBarItemOne.title = 'Notes (' + (++this.secondCounter) + ')';
    }
}
```

***home-page.ts***

```
import { EventData } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable';
import { StackLayout } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout';
import { HomeViewModel } from './home-view-model';

export function pageLoaded(args: EventData) {

    let page = <StackLayout>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HomeViewModel();
}
```

***home-page.xml***

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">
    <GridLayout rows="*, 2*, 2*">
        <SegmentedBar row="0" items="{{ segmentedBarItems }}" selectedIndex="{{ selectedBarIndex }}" />
        <Button row="1" text="Change first title" tap="{{ changeBarTitleOne }}" />
        <Button row="2" text="Change second title" tap="{{ changeBarTitleTwo }}" />
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Playground demo [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=ZBzVJS) (NativeScript + Angular)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution with this code for any people with the same problem:

First, define native element (don't forget to add #SegmentedBar to xml):

```
@ViewChild('SegmentedBar') SegmentedBar: ElementRef;
```

Change title:

```
this.SegmentedBar.nativeElement.items[3].title = 'Notes (' + this.order.notes.length + ')';
```

These code only refresh item title and not change position, etc.

Thanks
Jose